# How do I use html user input as a javascript variable in my function?

Tags: javascript, html, function, variables, input

I'm trying to create a dice rolling app that utilizes user input as the arguments for the function. I want to be able to enter the number of sides the dice should have, as well as how many dice should be rolled. For example, the user should be able to roll 5, 6-sided dice...or 2, 8-sides dice...etc...the two variables are up to the user to decide and input into the form. I've written some code with a "Dice Class" and a couple of functions which work when the two variables are hard coded. The problem is that for some reason the function cannot read the user input.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dicex.css" />
    <title>Dice</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <form id="form" class="form" onsubmit="return false">
        <h2>Dice Roller</h2>
        <div class="form-control">
          <input type="number" id="sides" placeholder="How many sides?" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-control">
          <input type="number" id="quantity" placeholder="How many dice?" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-control">
          <p id="results">My Results Go Here</p>
        </div>
        <button id="roll">Roll</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <script src="dice.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
// Query Selectors
let sides = document.querySelector("#sides").value;
let quantity = document.querySelector("#quantity").value;
let results = document.querySelector("#results");
let roll = document.querySelector("#roll");

// Dice Class
class Die {
  constructor(sides) {
    this.sides = sides;
  }

  roll() {
    let random_side = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.sides) + 1;
    return random_side;
  }
}

// Dice Roll Function
let create = function (e) {
  let a = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    let n = new Die(6);
    let r = n.roll();
    a.push(r);
  }

  let sum = a.reduce((a, b) => a + b);

  results.textContent = `You rolled ${a} for a total of ${sum}!`;
  e.preventDefault();
};

// Event Listeners
roll.addEventListener("click", create);
```

Comment: You need to get the input values after the user sets them ... inside `create()`. Right now you are getting the values when page loads only

Answer (score 0):

Use them inside the `create` function... which is triggered by an event.

```
// Query Selectors
//let sides = document.querySelector("#sides").value;
//let quantity = document.querySelector("#quantity").value;
let results = document.querySelector("#results");
let roll = document.querySelector("#roll");

// Dice Class
class Die {
  constructor(sides) {
    this.sides = sides;
  }

  roll() {
    let random_side = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.sides) + 1;
    return random_side;
  }
}

// Dice Roll Function
let create = function (e) {
  let a = [];

  // Here
  let sides = document.querySelector("#sides").value;
  let quantity = document.querySelector("#quantity").value;

  for (let i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {  // use here
    let n = new Die(sides);             // and here
    let r = n.roll();
    a.push(r);
  }

  let sum = a.reduce((a, b) => a + b);

  results.textContent = `You rolled ${a} for a total of ${sum}!`;
  e.preventDefault();
};

// Event Listeners
roll.addEventListener("click", create);
```

Comment: Thank you!  How simple...I just spent 2 hours trying to troubleshoot that haha. So is this a scope issue? I would have thought the function would have access to the global query selectors?

Comment: The function was acceeding the global values... Which are the ones on page load. The user changed the value of the inputs after, not the value of the variables. ;)